# change user login method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I'm editing a laravel project that use modules. I want change login field from email to mobile.
In the user login controller in the login module, there are the following codes:

```
$loggedIn = $this->auth->login(
    [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ],
    (bool) $request->get('remember_me', false)
);
```

I want user login with mobile, so I change the codes:

```
$loggedIn = $this->auth->login (
    [
        'mobile' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ],
    (bool) $request->get('remember_me', false)
);
```

But when I use this modified code, it does not change
This means that users can still log in by entering an email! No mobile!

Comment: change `$request->email` to `$request->mobile`

Comment: It made no difference!
The change you say is just a name change!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way...

**source** [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#remembering-users)

```
  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
        // The user is being remembered...
    }
```

Comment: I tried this way, it works with email, but when I change it to `'mobile'`, user not found!

Comment: check this ...`return User::where('mobile',$request->mobile)->first()`  . user exist or not for mobile number ..

Answer (score 0):

add this lines to `LoginController`:

```php
    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'mobile';
    }
```

Comment: I saw this way in Laravel documentation but not worked.

Comment: not error,It does not work and the user is not found with the entered mobile!

Comment: Yes.Even when I switch to mobile, the user can login by email,but not with mobile!

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom login like

```php
$user = User::where('mobile', $request->email)->first();

if (Hash::check($request->password,$user->password)) {
    auth()->login($user, (bool) $request->get('remember_me', false));  // it will login that user 
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods

> **NOTE**: in this way you have more control

Comment: what is difference between your code and my 2nd code?

Comment: `Argument 1 passed to Modules\User\Guards\Sentinel::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, array given, called in ..vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 307`

Comment: I changed `'email' => $request->email` to `'email' => $user->email` , before it: `$user = User::where('mobile' , $request->email) `. it works, but this method does not have a security problem?

Comment: @امیرحسینممتاز internally laravel does the same

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->mobile = $this->findMobile();
    }
    public function findMobile()
    {
        $login = request()->login;
        $fieldType = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'mobile';
        request()->merge([$fieldType => $login]);
        return $fieldType;
    }
    public function mobile()
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Try this with this code you can login  with email or mobile

Answer (score 0):

$customerInfo = array("email" => $email, "password" => $password);

```
   // $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($customerInfo)) {
        return redirect()->intended('home')
                    ->withSuccess('You have Successfully loggedin');
    }
```